Gradle build generates different jar when run from pipeline vs local
I am using github workflow to generate my jar file for java/spring application and then build docker image from it.
Problem is that when I run that image on local using docker it does NOT start grpc server.
I have done test to run on local (which is macos):
bash gradlew clean bootJar
docker build --build-arg JAR_FILE=build/libs/user-service-0.0.20.jar -t user-service-local:0.0.20 .

and then I have started my image and it works all good.
When I do same but via github workflow file and try to run pushed docker image on local it wont start grpc server.
I have verified both images (generated on local and vs on github) and their sha are identical.
So it leads me into thinking the problem is with gradle.
Here are bits and pieces which should help narrowing it down.

Github workflow
build:
    if: github.event.pull_request.merged == true
    needs: determine-version
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    name: Deploying ${{ needs.determine-version.outputs.new_version }}
    env:
      ECR_REPOSITORY: ${{ vars.ECR_REPOSITORY }}
      ECR_REGISTRY: ${{ vars.ECR_REGISTRY }}
    steps:
      - name: Checkout code
        uses: actions/checkout@v2

      - name: Set up JDK 8
        uses: actions/setup-java@v2
        with:
          java-version: '8'
          distribution: 'temurin'
          architecture: x64

      - name: Build with Gradle
        run: ./gradlew clean build --refresh-dependencies

      - name: Identify JAR file
        id: identify-jar
        run: |
          jar_file=$(basename $(ls build/libs/*.jar | grep -v '\-plain\.jar'))
          echo "Identified JAR file: $jar_file"
          echo "::set-output name=jar_file::$jar_file"

      - name: Debug JAR file
        run: echo "JAR file ${{ steps.identify-jar.outputs.jar_file }}"

      - name: Verify JAR file existence
        run: |
          if [[ ! -f build/libs/${{ steps.identify-jar.outputs.jar_file }} ]]; then
            echo "JAR file not found!"
            exit 1
          fi
          echo "JAR file found: build/libs/${{ steps.identify-jar.outputs.jar_file }}"

      - name: Update version in build.gradle
        run: |
          old_version=$(grep "^version = '" build.gradle | cut -d"'" -f2)
          echo "Old version: $old_version"
          sed -i "s/version = '.*'/version = '${{ needs.determine-version.outputs.new_version }}'/g" build.gradle
          new_version=$(grep "^version = '" build.gradle | cut -d"'" -f2)
          echo "Updated version in build.gradle: $new_version"

      - name: Commit and tag new version
        env:
          GITHUB_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.GH_PAT }}
        run: |
          git config --global user.name "github-actions[bot]"
          git config --global user.email "github-actions[bot]@users.noreply.github.com"
          git remote set-url origin https://x-access-token:${{ secrets.GH_PAT }}@github.com/${{ github.repository }}.git
          git add build.gradle
          git commit -m "Increment version to ${{ needs.determine-version.outputs.new_version }}"
          git tag -a "${{ needs.determine-version.outputs.new_version }}" -m "Release ${{ needs.determine-version.outputs.new_version }}"
          git push origin --tags
          git push origin main

      - name: Configure AWS Credentials
        uses: aws-actions/configure-aws-credentials@v1
        with:
          aws-access-key-id: ${{ secrets.AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID }}
          aws-secret-access-key: ${{ secrets.AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY }}
          aws-region: eu-west-2

      - name: Login to Amazon ECR
        id: login-ecr
        uses: aws-actions/amazon-ecr-login@v1
        env:
          AWS_REGION: eu-west-2

      - name: Build Docker image
        run: |
          docker build --build-arg JAR_FILE=build/libs/${{ steps.identify-jar.outputs.jar_file }} -t ${{ vars.ECR_REPOSITORY }}:latest -t ${{ vars.ECR_REPOSITORY }}:${{ needs.determine-version.outputs.new_version }} .

      - name: Tag Docker image
        run: |
          docker tag ${{ vars.ECR_REPOSITORY }}:${{ needs.determine-version.outputs.new_version }} ${{ vars.ECR_REGISTRY }}/${{ vars.ECR_REPOSITORY }}:${{ needs.determine-version.outputs.new_version }}
          docker tag ${{ vars.ECR_REPOSITORY }}:latest ${{ vars.ECR_REGISTRY }}/${{ vars.ECR_REPOSITORY }}:latest

      - name: Push Docker image
        run: |
          docker push ${{ vars.ECR_REGISTRY }}/${{ vars.ECR_REPOSITORY }}:${{ needs.determine-version.outputs.new_version }}
          docker push ${{ vars.ECR_REGISTRY }}/${{ vars.ECR_REPOSITORY }}:latest

Gradle-wrapper.properties
distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
distributionPath=wrapper/dists
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-7.3-bin.zip
zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
zipStorePath=wrapper/dists

build.gradle
plugins {
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '2.6.0'
    id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.0.11.RELEASE'
    id 'java'
    id 'com.google.protobuf' version '0.8.14'
}

group = 'com.uberkaretki.user'
version = '0.0.20'
sourceCompatibility = '1.8'

configurations {
    compileOnly {
        extendsFrom annotationProcessor
    }
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    mavenLocal()

    repositories {
        maven {
            name 'GitHub'
            url "https://maven.pkg.github.com/uberkaretki/common"

            credentials {
                username = 'xxx'
                password = 'yyy' // Just packages:read
            }
        }
    }

}

dependencies {
    implementation "com.uberkaretki:karetki-common:0.1.2"

    compileOnly 'org.projectlombok:lombok:1.18.22'
    annotationProcessor 'org.projectlombok:lombok'

}

protobuf {
    generatedFilesBaseDir = "$projectDir/src/main/java/generated"
    protoc {
        artifact = 'com.google.protobuf:protoc:3.10.1'
    }

    plugins {
        grpc {
            artifact = 'io.grpc:protoc-gen-grpc-java:1.25.0'
        }
    }

    generateProtoTasks {
        all()*.plugins {
            grpc {}
        }
    }
}

I have done test to run on local (which is macos):
bash gradlew clean bootJar
docker build --build-arg JAR_FILE=build/libs/user-service-0.0.20.jar -t user-service-local:0.0.20 .

and then I have started my image and it works all good.
